# Include jQuery function in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

I want to call my jQuery function into an HTML tag. My login form connects to an Azure database and I want when the client presses the Login button to appear modal pop-up with a specific message if the user is the database or not.

In my jQuery script, I want to handle that error by redirecting me to another page if the connection was true or change the message in the pop-up if not.

Right now, it doesn't get into the jQuery function and I only get the true message all the time, even if it was false.

jQuery script:

```
<script>
  function checkForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("https://studentshiftregister.azurewebsites.net/api/Login", function (data, status) {
      if (status === "200") {
        window.location.href = "#Portfolio";
        return true;
      } else {
        //display error information in the current form page
        $("#postLoginMessage").html("<font color=red>Login unsuccessfull!</font>");
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="https://studentshiftregister.azurewebsites.net/api/Login" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" onsubmit="checkForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-text" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center"><button id="myBtn" type="submit" class="input-btn" >Login</button></div>
</form>
<div id="myModal" class="modal" >

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" > 
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="postLoginMessage">Welcome back!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: are you sure the API is working? because it's returning 404

Comment: you are getting true in response? you are getting status: true in response.

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous, the return value of the callback function is not used.

Comment: The API is working, I just changed it for this example, it returns 200 for true and 401 for false

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `checkForm()` with no argument, but the function expects the first argument to be the `Event` object, so it can call `e.preventDefault()`. Change

```
onsubmit="checkForm()"
```

to:

```
onsubmit="checkForm(event)"
```

Comment: It's still not working, still return welcome back when it is false. I'm new to jQuery and I don't know what to change

Comment: Just the 401 Unauthorized when the user the doesn't exist.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof status, status)` show?